# Cannot install any fonts in Ubuntu

Tags: fonts

The ./font in the home directory didn't existed, so I created it manually. I've tried placing .otf/.ttf(or just the whole folder which contains type of font files) to the destination ~/.fonts and then entering this in terminal: `fc-cache -fv`.
The font-manager or fonts intaller nothing works. They either close unexpectedly, freezes or says "Install Fail".
I wanted to install powerfonts, nerd fonts (ubuntu mono, roboto mono) but I've also tried installing fonts from google fonts. Nothing worked.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.10.
I'm a new linux user, please guide me even if I've made mistakes.

Comment: **Install Font Manager**: `$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install font-manager`. To install fonts such as Tmes New Roman, Courier new, etc., install the following: `$ sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Comment: Thankyou, your comment worked for me.

Comment: Did you try Tmes New Roman, Courier new, etc.? Are they working @Syed Mushaheed?

Comment: yes they are working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe fonts are located in `usr/share/fonts` if i'm not mistaken

Comment: but why was I not able to install fonts with fonts or font manager? could you help?